# Can't set Tablix filter to a date type parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I right-click tablix and go to Filters in property page. 
There are 2 data parameters, @StartDate and @Enddate

If I add a new filter as "ActionDate between @StartDate and @EndDate, error thrown telling mismatched data type

I Add a new filter "ActionDate between Parameters!StartDate and Parameters!EndDate, no data is shown

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because @StartDate and @EndDate aren't being recognised - instead of using the parameter names as held in the query, you need to use the parameters as they would appear in SSRS expressions, which are almost certainly `Parameters!StartDate.Value` and `Parameters!EndDate.Value`.

You can select these in SSRS's Edit Expression dialog - like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe this problem cause from the defined type of your parameters.

Comment: @masoud-ramezani. you are sort of right. I used the wizard to create a report and tried using query parameter on the dimension value. The parameter was created as text type!!!, even thought the dimension is date. LOL